# Serialize an element value with its attributes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have an XML coming in this form:

```
<run>
    <foo status="1">111.9</foo>
    <fred status="0">5.5</fred>
</run>
```

I would like to deserialize this in either of these forms below (I'm undecided, and hoping an answer will help me decide, although I tend to prefer #1, for design aesthetics as much as anything else):

Case # 1

```
[Serializable]
public class DataValue
{
    [XmlAttribute("status")]
    public int Status { get; set; }
    // I need something here, but what?
    public float Value { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("run")]
public class DataBag
{
    [XmlElement("foo")]
    public DataValue Foo{ get; set; }
    [XmlElement("fred")]
    public DataValue Fred{ get; set; }
}
```

When I try this, I get a value of 0 for either member foo or fred.

Case # 2

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("run")]
public class DataBag2
{
    [XmlElement("foo")]
    public float Foo{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("foo")]
    [XmlAttribute("status")]
    public int Foo_status { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("fred")]
    public float Fred{ get; set; }

    [XmlElement("fred")]
    [XmlAttribute("status")]
    public int Fred_status { get; set; }
}
```

It compiles but I get an InvalidOperationException while reflecting Foo_status, for which the innermost exception is "For non-array types, you may use the following attributes: XmlAttribute, XmlText, XmlElement, or XmlAnyElement."

What can I do to end up with an actual value in case #1, or no exception (and a valid value and status) for case #2?

The code for the serialization goes like this:

```
// Case 1
using (var sr = new StreamReader("data.xml"))
{
    var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataBag));
    var run = (DataBag)xs.Deserialize(sr);
    Console.WriteLine("Got a run: {0}-{1}", run.Fred.Value, run.Fred.Status);
    // Issue here is that value is always 0, but status is accurate
}
// case 2
using (var sr = new StreamReader("data.xml"))
{
    var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DataBag2));// Exception here
    var run = (DataBag2)xs.Deserialize(sr);
    Console.WriteLine("Got a run: {0}-{1}", run.Foo, run.Foo_status);
}
```

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For case 1 you just need to mark it as XMLText:

```
    [XmlText]
    public float Value { get; set; }
```

Comment: Great Answer! I can now use the simple serialization model, where I don't have to derive from IXmlSerializable.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [`[XmlText]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute.aspx):

> Indicates to the XmlSerializer that the member must be treated as XML text when the class that contains it is serialized or deserialized.

Thus:

```
public class DataValue
{
    [XmlAttribute("status")]
    public int Status { get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public float Value { get; set; }
}
```

Case #2 just won't work as you want.  Adding `[XmlAttribute("status")]` to `Foo_status` means that `Foo_status` will be serialized as an attribute of `DataBag2`, not `Foo`.  Applying `[XmlElement("foo")]` as well then says it's an element of `DataBag2`, which is of course in conflict with other attribute.

There's no way with `XmlSerializer` for an outer container type to specify an attribute to be applied to a nested element.